# Is a 3ms ping between two differnt cloud providers possible

Tags: cloud

I am testing ping times and found that going from east coast data centers of an amazon ec2 linux instance to a windows azure instance has a ping time of 3ms.  Since it is so small it makes me wonder if I am doing something wrong. I believe the azure data center is in Virginia.  When I connect from my computer I get 57-60ms which makes me think my test is correct.  When I test 127.0.0.1 on the azure instance  I get 8-10ms which makes me think I should at least be getting above 10ms when testing ec2 to azure.  I just want to know if a 3ms ping is even possible between two computers in different data centers.  I can't ping from command line because neither box responds to standard pings.  My program sends a random number starts a timer and then checks that the return packet contains the number so I believe the test is correct.

```
  loop{
      byte[] senddata;
            senddata = CreatePacketString(
                        Guid.Parse(players.randomTestGuidPlayer[2]), 
                        players.udpc[2].packetnumber, moveto2);

            Random g = new Random();
            int k = g.Next(5000);
        players.udpc[2].packetnumber += k;

            Send(players.udpc[2].listener, getServerIP(), getServerPort(), senddata);

            long t1 = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;

            bool found = false;
            while (found == false)
            {
                byte[] data = IncomingPacket(players.udpc[2].listener.Receive(ref players.udpc[2].groupEP));

                byte[] packetnumberAsBytes = new byte[4];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 10, packetnumberAsBytes, 0, sizeof(Int32));
                Int32 gt = BitConverter.ToInt32(packetnumberAsBytes, 0);

                if (gt == players.udpc[2].packetnumber - k)
                {
                    found = true;
                }

                if(found == false)
                    System.Console.WriteLine(String.Format("UNEXPECTED"));

            }
            long t2 = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;

            System.Console.WriteLine(String.Format("pings {0}", t2 - t1));
 }
```

Comment: Alex, thanks for the information.  My ec2 instance is just a terminal so I don't think I can run azure speed test from the amazon instance.  If it was azure to azure in the same datacenter I would think 3ms may be possible.  I am still looking for bugs in the test because I think 3ms is impossible from ec2 to azure.  1 ms at speed of light is about ~200 miles and the ping is a round trip so the datacenters would have to be within ~300 miles of each other.

Comment: This question is off-topic for StackOverflow - it has nothing to do with programming. And ping time is not tied to physical location or physical distance.

Answer (score 0):

That is really depends on what is going on with the network in that exact moment.
You may try to login to the virtual machine and see the statistics using popular tools like [Azure Speed Test](http://www.azurespeed.com) - it will show you not only the ping, but many other relevant numbers.

And i would not try to compare any numbers that are available from the world with something that is happening inside of the cloud vendors network infrastructure. For example, datacenters in the Microsoft Azure cloud are in the owned network. I would guess that Amazon the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

It was a bad idea to call the send function before setting t1.

```
  Send(players.udpc[2].listener, getServerIP(), getServerPort(), senddata);

        long t1 = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
```

I believe these statements were not happening immediately after one another because the OS would pause the thread to handle the UDP send.  Then sometime later I would set the time but this really needs to happen before the send, because I needed to record that time out of the thread.  This resulted in pings that were way too low.